# Обновление json поля в таблце postgres

Tags: python, sql, json, postgresql

Пытаюсь добавить к существующим json данным еще больше данных формата ключ : значение. Достаю данные ищ постгреса запросом к полю и получаю словарь. После чего просто добавляю к словарю доп пару ключ значение следующим образом:

```
conn=Connection()
a=conn.get_user_data(user_id)[0][0]
a['new']='data'
```

Получаю обновленный словарь со всем нужными полями:

```
a={'index': True, 'old':'data' , 'new':'data'}
```

После пытаюсь заполнить столбец новыми данными следующим образом:

```
a = str(a)
a = a.replace("'",'"')
query = '''UPDATE table SET data = ('{}') '''.format(a)
conn.cursor.execute(query)
conn.connection.commit()
```

Получаю следующую ошибку:

> psycopg2.errors.InvalidTextRepresentation: invalid input syntax for
> type json LINE 1: UPDATE table SET data =
> ('{"inde...
> ^ DETAIL:  Token "True" is invalid. CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1:
> {"index": True...

Есть ли другой способ обновить json поле в postgresql или как я могу исправить свой способ, учитывая, что 'index' содержит BOOL True в БД?

Answer (score 0):

```py
import psycopg2 as pg
from psycopg2.extras import Json

with pg.connect('<conn string>') as conn, conn.cursor() as cur:
# Если у вас поле `data` имеет тип json, то так
    cur.execute(
        """
        update users set data = (data::jsonb || %s::jsonb)::json where id = %s
        """,
        (
            Json({'new': 'data'}),
            1
        )
    )
# Если jsonb то так
    cur.execute(
        """
        update users set data = data || %s::jsonb where id = %s
        """,
        (
            Json({'new': 'data'}),
            1
        )
    )
```